# Receiving wrong data via TCP Erlang

Tags: tcp, functional-programming, erlang

I'm trying to receive some data via a TCP socket. When I run the code below I get the output: localhost^V^A^@, I am aware that you need to convert data if sending it using binary, but since I am sending a list I thought it would have been received the same? Why does the Host string show correctly but the other data doesn't?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
cell_process(Port, X, Y)->
    Host = "localhost",
    Data = [Host,Port,X,Y],
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:connect(Host, 22, 
                                 [list, {packet, 0}]),
    ok = gen_tcp:send(Socket, Data),
    ok = gen_tcp:close(Socket).


server_process(ClientList)->
{ok, Listening_socket} = gen_tcp:listen(22, [list, {packet, 0}, 
                                        {active, false}]),
{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listening_socket),
    case gen_tcp:recv(Socket,0) of
        {ok,Message}->
            io:fwrite(Message);
        {error,Why}->io:fwrite(Why)
    end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Data = [Host,Port,X,Y]`is a iolist,not a list.
gen_tcp:send will convert Data to `[<<"localhost">>,<<22:8>>]`

here is the doc of iolist:

```
iodata() = iolist() | binary()
iolist()     maybe_improper_list(char() | binary() | iolist(), binary() | [])
maybe_improper_list()     maybe_improper_list(any(), any())
byte()     0..255
char()     0..16#10ffffmaybe_improper_list(T)     maybe_improper_list(T, any())
```

Comment: Okay thanks, but still how will I convert the data back to the original values?

Comment: @user2484294 Call `cell_process` with args as strings or binaries. You could also convert them in `cell_process` but that would make it a more specialised function and it looks like it should be general.

Comment: The key of iolist is avoid flatten handle,just pass them to low_level functions like `gen_tcp:send()`. In here you better send data `[iolist_size(Host),Host,Post]`, and in server ,matching like this `<<BinaryLen:8,Host:BinaryLen/binary,Post:8>>`